# Convert big number to single digit array

Tags: arrays, matlab

So, I need to convert any number to its reverse and put it in an array.

For example:

> 123456789 --> [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]

I managed to do it for small numbers like the example with this:

```
n=32134654654213
rev=(fliplr(num2str(n)));
mikos=length(rev);
array=[ ]
for i=1:mikos
   array=[array,str2num(rev(i))]
end
```

But when I put a big number like 564465426464334345413435541 the array is always `1x18 double` and does not show all the digits.

Any ideas?

`edit` As you tell me in comments, it is a limit of how many digits a double can hold. You are right, if I use a string input, it works as a charm. Still wondering hot to make it work as a function, with this form :

> function digits = GetDigits(n)

Comment: Because there is a limit on how big a number `n` can hold, as its a `double` type

Comment: Why not start with `n='564465426464334345413435541'`? If you keep it as a string you won't run into numeric limits.

Comment: Thank you for stating the limit on the big number.
If I make the input of n as string, it is ok.
But, I must use this "function digits = GetDigits(n)"
edited my OP

Comment: What does `num2str(564465426464334345413435541)` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have a limit on the number of digits a double can store. The limit on a uint64 is bigger (19), but still not sufficient to store your value. I would make sure it does not happen.

```
function digits = GetDigits(n)
%check if the value behaves as a normal integer
if isnumeric(n)
    if n==(n+1),error('n too big, supply as string instead');end
end
rev=(fliplr(num2str(n)));
mikos=length(rev);
array=[ ]
for i=1:mikos
   array=[array,str2num(rev(i))]
end

end
```